# Product measures in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, product-space

Suppose $(X,M,\mu)$ and $(Y,N,v)$ are $\sigma-$finite measure spaces. Is the following calculation correct?

$\int \chi_E(x,y) d\mu=\int (\chi_E)^y(x) d\mu=\int \chi_{E^y}(x)  d\mu=\mu(E^y)$ for a given $E\subset X\times Y$. It is given that $E^y$ is $\mu-$ measurable.

This is just for confirmation, because I am not sure whether my calculation is correct.

Comment: Be careful with notation: $\int \chi_E(x,y)d\mu$ is bad. I guess you wanted "for $y\in Y$ fixed, $\int\chi_E(x,y)d\mu(x)=\cdots$". If that is what you mean, yes.

Comment: Actually what I have to calculate is $\int (\int \chi_E d\mu)dv$. Then we have to fix $y$ in the inside integral. Isn't it?

Comment: I see the problem. I don't like how $\int(\int\chi_Ed\mu)d\nu$ is written, because $\chi_E$ is not a function on $X$, so $\int\chi_Ed\mu$ does not make sense (this is not your fault, of course). When dealing with integrals inside integrals, I always prefer to put the arguments (even if this is kind of pedantic). In this case, I would write $\int(\int\chi_E(x,y)d\mu(x))d\nu(y)$. Then for each $y$ you have to calculate $\int\chi_E(x,y)d\mu(x)$, which makes sense, just as you did.